# VB.NET - Navigating without loading another form

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently developing a simple enrollment system for our school project. I have multiple modules that when clicked will open a new form with another set of sub modules.

However, I hate how forms load every time I open a new form. Is there like a way that when I clicked say for example "Enrollment" button, instead of loading a new form, it will change all the controls instead. Tried using User Control but it keeps crashing my program down after I created 2 user controls and load them in one form.

[Main Form;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWaW0.png)
[Enrollment Sub Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h84O6.png)

Please help me guys.

Comment: Create UserControls instead of Forms and just replace them in the parent container.

Comment: TabPages representing discrete aspects is another option

Comment: @LarsTech how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LarsTech mentioned I would use user controls instead of forms.

Each user control would be setup the same way as your form is, but can be loaded to a panel on the main form, allowing for a single form to show all content.

```
Dim myControl = New ControlYouCreated
panel1.Controls.Add(myControl)
myControl.bringtofront
```

This for example, will bring in the contents of the user control you created, into your form1 panel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one concern though. I have two user controls and load them in one form. I can navigate to userctrl_2 after clicking a button by hiding userctrl_1. The thing is, I can no longer display userctrl_1 back. It remains hidden. Tried to use userctrl.show () and userctrl.Visible≈true but nothing seem to work.

Comment: It sounds like you have to bring userctrl_2 back to the top. Hold on and I'll get something working and post an example.

Comment: I've edited my code a little bit to show you how to fix your issue. You need to "bringtofront" for the control that you want to show.